# Import module on Python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to import a module on Python but I'm receiving the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_db_conn.py", line 8, in <module>
    from config import config_reader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Here's the folder structure:

```
config
 - __init.py
 - config_reader.py
 - config.ini 
db_functions
  - test_db_conn.py
```

And the code on 'test_db_conn.py':

```
# Import modules
from config import config_reader
import pymongo

# Query database and print result
db_client = pymongo.MongoClient(db_url)
db_status = db_client.test
print(db_status)
```

Are you able to help me with this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: your test file is already inside of config folder so you only need `import config_reader`

Comment: Sorry, that "folder structure" is wrong. I mistyped while creating the post. The test script is inside "db_functions" that is on the same level as the "config" folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the parent path of your project to the Python module search directory. I replicated your folder structure locally on my dev system, and was able to access a function named `config_reader` in the `config_read.py` module, within the `config` package.

```
import sys
import pathlib

parent_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent
sys.path.append(parent_dir.__str__())

from config.config_reader import config_reader
config_reader()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll test it as soon as I get to my computer. I'll update you than.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! It didn't work with that exact same code but you point me in the right direction to fix the issue! Thank you!